# Calculating the path integral for cubic interactions (perturbatively)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, action, interactions

I'm trying to apply the [Coleman-Weinberg mechanism](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Coleman-Weinberg_mechanism) to the weakly interacting, $g \ll 1$, $\mathbb{Z}_2$-symmetric $\phi^6$-theory in $d = 3 - \epsilon$ dimensions (in Euclidean signature)
\begin{equation}
S = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx \left( \frac{(\partial_\mu\phi)^2}{2} + \frac{g}{6!}\phi^6 \right) \ .
\end{equation}
As usual, I expand the classical field, $\phi_{cl}$, around quantum fluctuations, $\delta\phi$,
\begin{equation}
\phi = \phi_{cl} + \hbar\delta\phi \ ,
\end{equation}
and then I wish to path integrate out $\delta\phi$ (I will use units s.t. $\hbar = 1$). The first order terms of $\delta\phi$ vanish by virtue of the e.o.m. and we are left with higher orders. However, in order to find the $\beta$-function (upto order $g^2$) in doing this, we need to include two-loop diagrams. This means that I should path integrate out upto third order in $\delta\phi$
\begin{equation}
Z = \int\mathcal{D}\phi_{cl}e^{-S[\phi_{cl}]}\int\mathcal{D}\delta\phi e^{-\delta S}  \ , \\
\delta S = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx \left( \frac{(\partial_\mu\delta\phi)^2}{2} + \frac{g}{48}\phi_{cl}^4\delta\phi^2 + \frac{g}{36}\phi_{cl}^3\delta\phi^3 + ... \right) \ .
\end{equation}
Exactly how do I do this?

I know how to path integrate out the quadratic terms, $\delta\phi^2$, by keeping $\phi_{cl}$ fixed and writing the path integral as $\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}\log(-\partial^2 + \frac{g}{48}\phi_{cl}^4) \right)$ (where the $\phi_{cl}^4$ is to be treated as a mass for $\delta\phi$), but I'm unsure how to deal with the cubic terms, $\delta\phi^3$.

I think this can only be done perturbatively (w.r.t. $g \ll 1$) by summing over a number of Feynman diagrams, but which diagrams are these? In my case I'm only interested in terms upto order $g^2$.

I appreciate the help.

Edit: The path integral I want to compute perturbatively is on the form
\begin{equation}
Z = \int\mathcal{D}\phi\exp\left[ -\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx \left( \frac{(\partial_\mu\phi)^2}{2} + \lambda\phi^3 \right) \right] \ ,
\end{equation}
where $\lambda \ll 1$ is a dimension full coupling constant.